# Remove tinymce default html

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

Is it possible to remove tinymce default html?

```
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
```

Comment: +1 lol, half an hour ago I thought the same think, but then decided to leave it as it is, as it does not disturb me; it's only inserted on an empty editor;

Comment: Unfortunately, this sometimes leaks out when editor.save() is called within some of the TinyMCE events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those bogus elements are usually getting removed onSave or getContent().
You won't be able to see them using the code plugin eighter.

The br in this case is necessary in Firefox in order to be able to click into the paragraph.

Comment: Only `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'html' })` seems to remove bogus elements. `format:'raw'` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to apply a "untag" function over the iframe text, to make sure the user wrote something that is NOT tags, I mean, some innerHTML or pure text:

```
function untag(text){       
   var t = "" + text;                     
   t = t.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");  
   return t;
}

var msg = $('your_mce_iframe_id').html();

if( untag(msg) != "" ){
    // user wrote anything, validation ok
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing  `<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>` while getting tinymce content we can simply tell tinymce not to produce these bogus elements by using the below configuration entry.

tinymce.init({
        forced_root_block : false
});

If you set this option to false it will never produce P tags on enter key press.

Comment: I added this entry to my init but it made no difference :/

Comment: If you add `tinymce.init({ forced_root_block : false });` it only removes the specified block element (in my case `<p></p>`).  This still leaves the `<br data-mce-bogus="1">` in the editor.  This is a problem for me using parsley.js to validate.  I'm trying to enforce a rule that states the field is required.  Parsley thinks the "dta-mce-bogus" text is legit and so it validates as true.  When my record is inserted, the field is an empty string.